# Why does my interpolated SQL query have these extra quotation marks?

Tags: python, lambda, psycopg2

I set queries like following . I'd like to replace `bucket_name` and `file_name` with variables

This query is executed by `psycopg2`

```
query = '''copy table.test
                from 's3://%(bucket_name)s/%(file_name)s.txt'
                iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123453215125:role/test'
                timeformat as 'auto'
                ACCEPTINVCHARS 
                delimiter '\t';'''
```

And I get bucket name and file name

```
    bucket_name = get_bucket_name(event)
    file_name = get_file_name(event)
```

After that, I executed query, but it returned errors

```
cur.execute(query, {'bucket_name':bucket_name,'file_name':file_name})
```

```
[ERROR] SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "expired" LINE 2: from 's3://'expired-test-bucket... ^ Traceback (most recent cal
```

It seems that `bucket_name` is replaced with single quotation `'expired-test-bucket'`

My desired result is `expired-test-bucket`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try to use python's string format() with {} placeholders for bucket name and filename.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656545/postgresql-syntax-error-at-or-near) can help a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters in parameterized queries *do not* work like string interpolation, even if you [use `pyformat` binding style that happens to look like old-school `%`-based string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql). The quotes are there because the database engine is expecting you to use the placeholder to represent an entire parameter, and putting quotes (and potentially various forms of escaping) into the final query text *by design*, *specifically to prevent* the security hole that results from interpolating user data directly into a query.

If you need to use user data to build up a value that is used in a query, then do just that, as separate steps: first, use Python string formatting to create the raw underlying value, and then use the SQL engine's functionality to make it safe to put that value into a query.

So, something like:

```
bucket_name = get_bucket_name(event)
file_name = get_file_name(event)
url = f's3://{bucket_name}/{file_name}.txt'

query = '''copy table.test
           from %s
           iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123453215125:role/test'
           timeformat as 'auto'
           ACCEPTINVCHARS 
           delimiter '\t';'''

cur.execute(query, (url,))
```